# how to relate images to article id

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website using php and mysql in which I want to save part of images' name as article id.

Eg: image_[$articleID]_1.jpg

Currently I am taking the article id as "querying the last id from article table and adding one to it".

I want to know whether this is a right way to do it, because I am giving the article id to images before inserting the actual article to database.

In the worst case scenario I am wondering that what will happen if 10 users are inserting an article at the same time.

Does anyone of you know a proper logic to accomplish this or am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could run into trouble in this situation. There are two solutions to this:

1. Use an auto-increment column; insert a new article into the database *before* creating the image filename, and update the new record afterwards.
2. Create a lock on the images table before you start to insert records, and release it once you're done updating the database.

Option 1 is my preferred option; it allows for concurrent use (nobody has to wait before all other users are finished), and it also relieves you of the task of determining the last ID.

Comment: Regarding option 1, how can I get the respective article id after I insert new article into database, to use the article id in naming the images?